# Entity Framework Hangs After Query Completes Before Connection is Closed

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, logging, entity-framework-6

I am trying to improve performance of a relatively complicated entity framework query. Using the `DbContext.Database.Log` action I examined the ouput while executing my main query of interest and I noticed something odd. According to the log, the query itself is taking only ~ 10,000 ms, however there is over a minute between when the query "completes" and when the connection is closed. I have no idea what is happening in this time as the log shows a blank line. Here is the output:

> 2018-09-07 14:10:34,641 [1] INFO EntityDataRepository [jobInstanceID: 0] - -- Executing at 9/7/2018 2:10:34 PM -07:00
>
> 2018-09-07 14:10:46,421 [1] INFO EntityDataRepository [jobInstanceID: 0] - -- Completed in 11776 ms with result: SqlDataReader
>
> 2018-09-07 14:10:46,458 [1] INFO EntityDataRepository [jobInstanceID: 0] -
>
> 2018-09-07 14:11:48,667 [1] INFO EntityDataRepository [jobInstanceID: 0] - Closed connection at 9/7/2018 2:11:48 PM -07:00

Could someone please educate me on what is going on here? See below for a simplified/generic version of the code:

```
(from child in entities.SelectMany(e => e.children.Where(childFilter))
join read in childReads on child.ID equals read.childID
join readType in readTypes on read.readTypeID equals readType.ID
where readFilter
select new {child, read, readType}).ToList()
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-connection-pooling

Comment: @PaulAbbott I read that article and I don't see how it applies here, could you please elaborate? I am only seeing this issue occur when executing this large query, not shorter queries earlier in the application. If you're suggesting the time is taken up returning the connection to the pool, it doesn't make sense to me why that would take 10x as long as executing the query itself (especially since I am using windows authentication and this is my only connection to the DB right now).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 2018-09-07 14:10:46,421 [1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-query-stats-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) INFO EntityDataRepository [jobInstanceID: 0] - -- Completed in 11776 ms with result: SqlDataReader

That means that `SqlCommand.ExecuteReader()` has completed, and the server is starting to return rows to the client.  The query in SQL Sever is *still executing* at this point.  It may have spooled all the query results, or it may have just found and returned the first few matching rows using a streaming query plan.  So for your `IQueryable<T>.ToList()` to complete, the query needs to finish executing on the server, the result rows have to be transmitted to the client, and EF has to read the rows and materialize them into class instances of type `T`.

The client-side work can be analyzed with [Visual Studio Profiler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/profiling/beginners-guide-to-performance-profiling?view=vs-2017) , performance counters, or the [System.Diagnostics.Process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process?view=netframework-4.7.2).

SQL Server tracks the [query execution stats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-query-stats-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) for queries in the plan cache, and for all queries if using [Query Store](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/monitoring-performance-by-using-the-query-store?view=sql-server-2017) in SQL 2016+.  The stats will show you the query elapsed time, which includes the time waiting on the client to read (and process) rows and all other waits, and the "worker time" which is the CPU time used by the query.  Query Store in SQL 2017 and Azure SQL Database also tracks wait stats for each query, so you can distinguish between waiting on the client (`ASYNC_NETWORK_IO`) and other waits like data file reads (`PAGEIOLATCH`), lock waits (`LCK_*_*`), etc.